# Why am I sometimes not allowed to delete a folder until I delete its contents by hand? (Windows)

Tags: windows, permissions

Sometimes, when I try to delete a folder in Windows, I get a message that I need permission from [my current account] to delete that folder. Which is weird, because I'm already logged in as that user. However, when I open the folder, select all contents, and delete them (without any sort of prompt), I can go back up and delete the original folder without the security prompt.

This happens most often in project folders created by Visual Studio (often, the .vs and .git folders cause this trouble) but it has happened with other folders as well. It also happens recursively: I open a problematic folder, delete all contents, get a message that a bunch of subfolders can't be deleted, open each subfolder, delete all contents, etc.

If I check the folder with Process Explorer, it can't find any attached processes to the folder or any of its contents.

It feels like this would be easy to automate, but why does this happen in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

I have often wondered the same thing. Unix(linux) based systems do not exhibit this problem and my guess is there is an entwined kernel problem MS is unwilling to take on.

I have investigated this several times. I am trying to help you out, but by no means is my knowledge a definitive answer. I don't remember this problem until win7 and the fact that it persists makes me believe the problem is too complicated and deep in the MS kernel for them to want to fix it.

1. The first possibility is other processes are in some way jammed or deadlocked. It might be as simple as the File Explorer accessing but not freeing the program when it wants the program's icon.
2. Another possibility is that the MS caching program has some unknown problem or is confused, whereby some process or damen has told the file manager it is in use, or perhaps should be kept available.
3. Or the ownership gets screwed up. Perhaps after accessing it, the file properties table shows the system is using or having control of it and no user has privileges to do something to it. This may be associated with a file lock issue.
4. My best guess, and its a shot in the dark, is somehow the file and the memory manager get screwed up and the files information becomes un-editable - even by the system or kernel.

One clue that points to a kernel cache / memory / or file manager problem is that it disappears after a reboot (perhaps indicating a ownership or in-use file lock problem). Whatever the problem, it is a major Microsoft screw up (and they are aware of it) and their best and brightest programmers are unable to resolve it in cost and resource effective way.

Comment: Any chance it's just a super duper "are you sure you really want to do this?" protection to help you avoid accidentally deleting files?  It allows deleting the directory after the files are gone.  (Maybe it's a feature rather than a bug.)

Comment: Doubtful, because 99% of folders with contents can just be deleted without any prompt whatsoever.

Comment: As long as it isn't a system disk I've found that forcing Windows to unmount and remount the disk using `chkdsk d: /f` also releases whatever is "locking" the folders.